Generating ±10V(1.5A) from an 11V input
I want to make ±10V (1.5A) from an 11V input, I found the following design (LTC3260), but the issue is that it can make 100mA max, so one solution would be I can make several of these in parallel, would you please let me know if there is any any other soltion?


Yes, get another regulator or regulators. Especially look into having separate ones for positive and negative.

If you get several of these then it would suggest that mechanical real estate on your PCB is not an issue. So that begs the question: why do you want a dual supply in the first place?

login https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator?powerSupply=0

A dual supply servo uses a half bridge , while a full bridge runs on V+ only. +10 only needs a FET LDO

Design by Missing Specs
Input = 11 V Tolerance =?
Output = +/- 10 V  1.5A ,  15 W each, Ripple = ?, Load = ?? Audio or motor
When the regulator only has to drop <10% or 1V this makes linear regulators as efficient as switched mode.  There are many choices now with this range and low dropout using FETs. If your load is a dynamic motor, then a push-pull linear regulator is needed rather than the single FET types so that it can reduce back EMF for braking.  TI and Linear Tech both have online design tools you can also use with a free registered email account.
https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator?powerSupply=0

-10V 1.5A 0.1% ripple

If your application is a dynamic load such as a servo motor system then ripple is not a critical factor with a clean Vref to regulate servo error. But otherwise you ought to specify output ripple as 50mV or similar unless you need an audio amplifier with very low ripple.  But if you have a class D audio amp, then IMD issues can occur mixing frequency products requires some attention to ESR of output caps or PSRR.
Dual supplies are necessary when you have only a single-ended driver.  But with a differential driver, you only need a single supply.  Differential drivers include Full FET bridges with linear feedback for switching with PWM.
There is no answer until all the design requirements are specified upfront.
The spec. is a dynamic part of the design to get things right the first time and one of the most important lessons not taught in uni.
I could discuss more, like the Make vs. Buy budget, technology SMT or THT, surge power, environmental stress, packaging, availability, efficiency vs. cost vs. size tradeoffs, thermodynamics of heat dissipation, etc.

Yes, you can, this is the wrong way to go about it if you don't have noise requirements.
A better thing would be to use a DC DC converter to generate the negative rail, these converters are cheap and easy to use (you can get them in 12V versions):
Generating negative voltage rail using P7805 DC-DC converter
If you do have noise requirements, use a DC DC in the configuration above with a higher voltage and then step it down if you don't care about losing a little bit of power.

If I may, I feel it's rather important to note that it's a switching regulator and not a linear one. I don't think you can do this with a linear regulator. To add on, I believe the idea is to use a buck converter as an inverting buck-boost converter to get the negative voltage. I did this once with an LM2596.

I did something like this once. I used a buck-converter IC (the LM2596 at the time) to step down an input voltage to a lower positive output voltage, and I used the same IC in an inverting buck-boost configuration to get a negative output voltage. You might want to have a look at that concept if you're okay with switching regulators.
